# AWK, count variable does not return 0

Tags: awk

So I have a program almost finished using AWK inside of Unix/Linux! I have to return a count, sum, max, min, and average. The program works when numbers are found. But, if no numbers are found and count does not iterate... I don't get back 0. I get back something like, "1a2,5".
Here is my code,

```
#! /bin/awk -f

{
sum += $1
}

/[0-9]+/{ 


if (NR >= 1){
    if ($0 != 0 &&  NF == 1){
        if ($0 !~ /[A-Za-z]/){

             min = (NR==1 || $1<min ? $1 : min)
             max = (NR==1 || $1>max ? $1 : max)
             mean = sum/NR

        count+=1  
        }
    } else if ($0 == 0)
    {exit(0)
}
}
  }


END{
printf("# items: %d \n",count)
printf("Total:   %lf\n", sum)
printf("Maximum: %lf\n", max)
printf("Minimum: %lf\n", min)
printf("Average: %lf\n", mean)
}
```

What am I forgetting/needs to be changed so count can return as 0 if nothing is found. Thank you

Comment: please update the question to include the sample input data that generates `1a2,5`; also include the complete output from running your script against the sample data

Comment: Regarding `if (NR >= 1)` - think about what circumstances could lead to that condition being false. When would the current line number in any input be `0` or negative? The answer is "never". I expect you meant to write some other condition there.

Comment: running your code against various inputs (blank lines, non-numerics, etc) always generates expected results (eg, a bunch of `0's`), but I'm running `GNU awk 5.1.0` which tends to be a bit forgiving with datatype mismatches (eg, `sum+=$1` where `$1` is a non-numerics); soooo, it may help if you could also update the question with the output from `awk --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /bin/awk -f

# Nothing to do
NF > 1 {
    next
}

# now $0 == $1

# Only with numbers
#$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {
# or
$1 ~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/ {
    # exit if zero found
    if ($1 == 0) {
        exit 0
    }
    # compute
    sum   += $1
    min    = (NR==1 || $1<min ? $1 : min)
    max    = (NR==1 || $1>max ? $1 : max)
    mean   = sum/NR
    count += 1
}

END {
    printf("# items: %d \n", count)
    printf("Total:   %lf\n", sum)
    printf("Maximum: %lf\n", max)
    printf("Minimum: %lf\n", min)
    printf("Average: %lf\n", mean)
}
```